# Background property does not work for jpg

Tags: html

I want to show a background image for my web page and I have one jpg for that purpose. I am using IE 8 and Notepad to write my html page. So I preferred to use `body` tag with Background property set to the image path. Very simple! But to my surprise, it does not show the image at all. When I tried the same path inside an Img tag on same page, it works. Also, when I tried another jpg in the `body` tag, it also worked!

```
<body background="images/myimage.jpg">
...
...
</body>
```

Finally, I decided to convert the image into png format and then it worked.

```
<body background="images/myimage.png">
...
...
</body>
```

Am I missing anything here in jpg case? Or body tag does not support jpg of particular size, something like that? This looks strange behavior to me. Any help appreciated.. thanks!

Comment: You should avoid using the `background` attribute. Use CSS instead!

Comment: Btw, you should upgrade to a standards compliant browser like Firefox, or Chrome, because as web gurus it is our place to educate the "masses" away from using the non-standard compliant browsers Microsoft came up with to make our lives difficult. :) Also, If you develop using an IE you are libel to create problems in all the standards compliant browsers, while if you develop using a compliant browser (i.e. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera... IE9?) you will only have to fix the IEs.

Comment: @SamStar: Sounds logical now!

Comment: Hehe, yea I hit the add comment button before I meant to earlier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML you have should work - check to make sure that the URL to the image is correct. Also ensure that the jpg file is saved in RGB format, as most browsers cannot display CMYK jpegs.

That being said, you should really use CSS to separate your HTML structure from the styling and UI concerns. To do this, remove the `background` property from the `body` element and instead put this in a CSS file:

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/myimage.jpg');
}
```

Comment: I converted my png back to jpg and now its working fine..! but earlier it was not working.. I think it might be something with RGB stuff as you said

Answer (score 0):

It's better to work with CSS :

```
body { background-image: url(images/myimage.jpg); }
```

Answer (score 0):

a cleaner solution is

```
<style type="text/css">
  body{background:url("images/myimage.jpg");}
</style>

<body>
.....
....
</body>
```